# Overflow error when doing arithmetic operations with constants

Tags: c#

I tried the following code :

```
int x, y;
x = y = int.MaxValue;

int result = x + y;
```

This code work fine and result will contain -2 (I know why).

But when doing this :

```
const int x = int.MaxValue;
const int y = int.MaxValue;

int result = x + y;
```

This will not compile because of overflow problem.Why ?

Comment: I am totally intrigued by this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because both `x` and `y` are compile-time constants, so is `x + y`. The compiler *knows* that the result will overflow, so it complains about it.

You can fix this by using an `unchecked` expression:

```
int result = unchecked(x + y);
```

From section 7.6.12 of the C# 5 specification - after listing `+`, `-`, `/` and `*`:

> When one of the above operations produce a result that is too large to represent in the destination type, the context in which the operation is performed controls the resulting behavior:
>
> - In a `checked` context, if the operation is a constant expression (§7.19), a compile-time error occurs.
> - In an `unchecked` context, the result is truncated by discarding any high-order bits that do not fit in the destination type.
>
> For non-constant expressions (expressions that are evaluated at run-time) that are not enclosed by any `checked` or `unchecked` operators or statements, the default overflow checking context is `unchecked` unless external factors (such as compiler switches and execution environment configuration) call for checked evaluation.
>
> For constant expressions (expressions that can be fully evaluated at compile-time), the default overflow checking context is always `checked`. Unless a constant expression is explicitly placed in an `unchecked` context, overflows that occur during the compile-time evaluation of the expression always cause compile-time errors.

Comment: Maybe off-topic  but, does unchecked reduce compile time when used for large bodies?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: I would be very surprised if you could find a real-world example where the difference was measurable.

Comment: Question Jon:  Is it reasonable that one would actually *want* to do this?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you very much for your answers to my questions.Very fast and very clear :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I thought msvc was checking function calls deeply so      int b=unchecked(numaExample()); would be faster. Thank you very much.

Comment: @John: There are times when it's useful to be able to express constants in an unchecked way, yes - e.g. for bit patterns. Fairly rare though.

Comment: @John One example is when you need to specify a [HRESULT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) as an ordinary `int` which is signed, from the hexadecimal representation. It looks like `int hr = unchecked((int)0x80070005);`.